# App Engine Flex custom - missing project files in Dockerfile build process

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

I'm trying to deploy Java app using App Engine Flex, but unfortunately - when deployment comes to stage when Docker image is being built, it seems to be ran in some isolated environment, and not in my local directory, with all required files for build process.

My `app.yaml` file looks like this:

```
service: default
env: flex
runtime: custom
handlers:
  - url: .*
    script: auto
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
network: {}
```

And my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ls -halt
CMD ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

I'm running commands:

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file mykeyfile.json
gcloud --quiet --project myprojectname app deploy app.yaml
```

`mykeyfile.json` holds credentials for Service Account with Owner role.

Command `RUN ls -halt` displays, that directory is empty - no files were copied from my machine.

How can I provide required files to be used during Docker image build?

Comment: Are there any error on the deployment logs? If so, could you share them?

Comment: @RafaelLemos no, no errors - just missing files.

Comment: Maybe a permissions issue? Maybe try `chmod a+r` in your application directory?

Comment: So, you want to get the files from you filesystem, correct? Have you followed these [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/intellij/deploy-flex#deploy), more specifically the Deployment source Configuration? It's in there that you point to the local deployment archive.

Comment: @speedplane Tried it, no luck.

Comment: @RafaelLemos This is correct. I was following [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/quickstart) instructions, as I want to do it from command line.

Comment: Can you share your `.gcloudignore` file? it's possible that the files/directories are being marked to be ignored during deploy. Also, are those configuration yaml files? Cause I found this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/testing-and-deploying-your-app#deploying_a_service_3) that says `Specifying no files with the command deploys only the app.yaml file in your current directory`, but there is a workaround to that as shared on the same link, let me know if this helps

Comment: @RafaelLemos nice idea about `.gcloudignore` - I do have it (totally forgot about it) and it is excluding `target` directory with `jar` inside. I'll investigate it today and let you know!

Comment: @RafaelLemos Bingo! That was it - my `jar` file was in `.gcloudignore`, so it was not included. Now it works! Could you post it as regular answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the files that are missing from the deploy are not listed in your `.gcloudignore` file.

As per the `.gcloudignore` [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore):

> If there is a file called `.gcloudignore` in the top-level directory to upload, the files that it specifies will be ignored.

Maybe during the deploy the files/directories were added to the `.gcloudignore` file by mistake, so by removing the files you desire to be deployed from the `.gcloudignore` file you will be able to do so.